# Attempting to update data in a mysql table using jtable

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jtable

Hi as the above says i'm attempting to change data already retrieved, but have no idea how to go about it, basically i want to change a piece of data, for example a part name from Toyota to Supra using jtable

this is what i have so far to retrieve data from the mysql db

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)p1.getModel();
    try{
            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            Connection conn=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/in1010gp33?user=abnd165&password=110016441");
            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
            String query="Select * from parts;";
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
            String d1=rs.getString("PartName");
            String d2=rs.getString("Manufacturer");
            String d3=rs.getString("VehicleType");
            String d4=rs.getString("Years");
            String d6=rs.getString("Price");

            model.addRow(new Object[]{d1,d2,d3,d4,d6});
                    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    conn.close();
        }
    catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
                      }       



    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}
```

Comment: What is the  problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) to your `JTable`. What ever data changes you do in the table do it on the table model. So finally save the data in the table model to the data base.

Updating the table can be done using [setValueAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method. Start looking at [How to use Table.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)